# Knockout's renderTemplate not binding $root

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to create a table, leveraging Knockout, where I can select one, have some functionality be inserted underneath the selected row, do some stuff, and be able to remove the inserted row. I can actually get the row insertion to work correctly, but am losing functionality which is bound to a parent of the looped items.

The HTML looks like so:

```
<table data-bind="visible: currentRecord() === null">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Affiliation</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'row-template', foreach: records}">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use two templates (one for a single row, and one for the row that contains the single row)

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/html">
    <tr class="actual-row">
        <td class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e" data-bind="insertRow: {
            templateName: 'custom-template', 
            rowIdentifier: 'extra-content', 
            singleRowTemplate: 'row-template',
            data: $data}">
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Affiliation"></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.clickMe">Click Me!</a>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="custom-template" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'row-template' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<tr id="extra-content">
    <td colspan="4" > 
        <div>You have: <input type="number" data-bind="value: currentAmount,     valueUpdate: 'keypress'" /> </div>
        <div>You need <strong data-bind="text: Max - currentAmount()" > </strong> more</div > 
    </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

During creation, the binding is perfect. I can click the *Click Me!* anchor just fine. However, when I execute the code to insert the row, it runs a custom binding handler that calls

```
ko.renderTemplate(value.templateName, value.data, {}, cell.parent(), "replaceNode");
```

where

- value is the JS object passed into the insertRow bindingHandler
- cell is the jQuery object of the TD element clicked to insert / remove special row.

I suspect that the relationship between the individual record and its parent record is lost and I don't know to leverage that. Can anyone help me?

I have a fiddle that I've been playing around with [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dvancuyk/sQvUK/3/)

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery to remove elements that have already been bound with Knockout. This will confuse Knockout; try to use Knockout-native ways of dealing with this (e.g. `if` bindings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be solved in more simple way. You even don't need write so complicated custom binding since expandable row is same for every superhero.

Just add 2 rows for every superhero but make one row invisible:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
    <tr class="actual-row">
        <td class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e" 
        data-bind="click: expanded.toggle">
            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Id" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Affiliation"></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.clickMe">Click Me!</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="extra-content" data-bind="visible: expanded">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div>You have:
                <input type="number" data - bind="value: currentAmount, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" />
            </div>
            <div>You need <strong data-bind="text: Max - currentAmount()"></strong > more </div> 
</td> </tr>

</tbody>
```

Let `visible` bound to some observable value inside row data:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.records(), function(rec){
    rec.expanded = ko.observable(false);
    rec.expanded.toggle = function(){
        rec.expanded(!rec.expanded());
    };
});
```

So that way you'll get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/sQvUK/6/

*P.S. The only thing that remains undone is class toggler for your arrow icons.*

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. This worked great with what I was trying to accomplish and is easier to style correctly to boot. Thanks!